# How to update my JavaFX GUI elements while program is running

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I want to be able to see updates on my graphical interface while the program is executing and not to wait till the click event on button ends

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {
@FXML
private label label;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
}

private void Event(ActionEvent event) {
    // start is a button
    if (event.getSource() == Start) {
      // calculations
      // updating label
      label.setText(" update me ");
      // other calculations
      // updating label for the second time
      label.setText(" update me ");
    }
  }
}
```

This is a simple example of my code (javaFXML), please note that the calculations and updates are more complicated than the demonstrative example and takes too much time to execute that's why I want to preview updates while executing.

Comment: You'll want to move the work onto a background thread—see [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) and the [`javafx.concurrent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. You can then bind the `Label` to the `message` property of the [`Task`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and use [`updateMessage`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateMessage(java.lang.String)) inside said `Task`.

Comment: @Slaw thanks for the help i'll try to  understand your refrences .

Comment: When you are stuck, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. And unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 0):

You should Know and use the threads concept

Your code will be like this:

```
if (event.getSource() == Start) {

       new Thread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 //do the calculations
                 System.out.println("calculations is finished");
             }
       }).start();

      // updating label
      label.setText(" update me ");

      new Thread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 //do the other calculations
                 System.out.println("calculations is finished");
             }
       }).start();
      // updating label for the second time
      label.setText(" update me ");
    }
```

But you must be aware the synchronization problems that may occur between the calculations.
I recommend you follow this course :
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBB24CFB073F1048E